# Anonymously login auto generated user

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform

I see that objectId of users generated locally and users created after anonymous login are not the same.

For example

```
    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let localUser = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId! 
    print(localUserId) // "obj1"

    PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            let annonUserId: String = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!
            print(annonUserId) // obj2
    }
```

I want that obj1 to persist throughout the anonymous login phase.

Can I somehow "attach" the locally created user and login him anonymously? or is auto generated users are only useful for when you later upgrade him to a user&pass / social based logins ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to use the anonymous user for (is it actually helping you)?

Comment: @Wain yes, i'm allowing user to be in "invisible" mode, where they can create profile but not "opt in" to registration and becoming active participants in the community. Anonymous Users (should I get them to work /w parse) sound perfect for this use case.

Comment: What profile details are the users specifying then? If you aren't storing any details then why does the anonymous user id matter? If you are then you should create a proper user with an automatically generated username and password.

Comment: @Wain you are too quick to recommend solution without understanding my use case. I need to be able to identify my users, and I did not say I'm not storying information. Only that I'm allowing ease-in on boarding without requiring the user to register as the first experience he is getting.

Answer (score 1):

`PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock` is defined to destroy existing anonymous user data and create a new clean anonymous user. You should only do that when the user is logged out.

If you enable anonymous users then one will be created initially and you can add whatever details you want to that. Then, later, when the user wants a real account use `signUp:` on the `PFUser` to convert it.

Note that anonymous users aren't real, you can't use them for everything. So, you may have some issues with them actually participating with other users. If this is the case then you may need to create real placeholder users with auto-generated login details and convert that at a later date by updating the username and sending a forgotten password e-mail (or similar).